# During automated RHHI installation, what do they mean with 'Virtual Machine Mac address'

Tags: rhel, virtual-machine

When I want to run the ansible scripts for automatically installing RHHI on my physical (RHEL+KVM based) hosts.
They ask to edit a json file in which I am required to give **the FQDN and MAC address of a VM**. (Which I have not created yet)

I'm just a little clueless about what they mean with '**MAC address of VM'**.
Is it the *MAC of one of the NICs*? or which other MAC address do they expect?

Comment: What else is supposed to have a MAC, if not a NIC?

Comment: What version of RHHI? Where are you being asked to put in a MAC address exactly? I can't find anything like that in the actual deployment instructions from Red Hat.

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_hyperconverged_infrastructure_for_virtualization/1.5/html-single/automating_rhhi_for_virtualization_deployment/index#setting-deployment-variables

Chapter 6.3 they ask to edit some variables in the JSON file. One of which is the VM's MAC address.

Comment: When a virtual machine is created it (often) gets its own (virtual) network interface, which also has a unique MAC address. If you haven't created the VM yet, then there is probably some templating system or some other mechanism that writes the JSON document on the fly.

Comment: I don't think there is. I suspect I might have missed something where I would have been told to create a VM maybe. Because when running the ansible playbook, I add the --extra-vars='@he_gluster_vars.json' from where it reads the variables listed in the link I posted yesterday.

If anyone has any experience using these Ansible roles to install rhhi, please let me know what should be done here. Very much obliged

Comment: @Bananguin You might have a point actually. I just found some scripts where a VM is automatically installed. But in THAT script they still try to use the variables defined in the aforementioned JSON file. 
But it's pretty strange.. I think they just might need the vNIC from the host machine then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON file asks for **'A valid MAC address FOR the hosted Engine Virtual Machine'**

Which means it does NOT expect me to already have installed a VM, I need to give it a MAC so it can create the VM for me.

Comment: That is usual in provisioning, it will happen on other plataforms. Get used to it.